# Vous pourriez me dire / vous me diriez

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

Quelqu'un m'a demandé une liste, je lui ai répondu :

> Au cas où, je vous envoie toute la liste, puis vous **pourriez** me dire si
> je dois trier.

Est-ce que la deuxième phrase, avec "diriez", est correcte aussi ? Je pense qu'il est possible de sous-entendre un conditionnel de suggestion ici *Si vous vouliez bien, vous me le diriez*.

> Au cas où, je vous envoie toute la liste, puis vous me **diriez** si je
> dois trier.

Comment: Avec la virgule, on comprends tout de suite mieux :-)

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre la phrase mais en voici une interprétation :

> Si je vous envoie toute la liste, vous pourrez me dire si je dois faire un tri ?

Après les clarifications en commentaire :

> Je vous envoie toute la liste au cas où. Vous pourrez me dire si je dois faire un tri.

ou

> Au cas où, je vous envoie toute la liste. Dites-moi si je dois faire un tri.

Comment: Merci, oui, c'est bien aussi. Voici le contexte : quelqu'un m'a demandé de lui envoyer la liste de mes nouvelles publiées. Je n'ai pas compris s'il voulait uniquement les nouvelles publiées dans des revues, ou en ligne aussi. Je voulais dire "au cas où, ...", "au cas où" = "in case" --> Martin always has spare bulbs in his car, just in case.

Comment: Il est possible de mettre "au cas où" à la fin _Je vous envoie toute la liste au cas où_.

Comment: Oui, on peut mettre "au cas où" à la fin avec le sens de *just in case*.

Comment: et au début aussi, avec une virgule.

Comment: Merci, mais est-ce que "vous me diriez si je dois trier" est correct dans mon contexte ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas incorrect mais il manque un peu un objet au verbe, "si je dois **la** trier" est mieux mais je préfère "faire un tri" ou "faire du tri" qui me semblent plus transmettre l'idée "on garde/on ne garde pas" alors que "la trier", on dirait qu'on classe par ordre suivant un critère indéfini. C'est sûrement un peu subjectif, juste mon ressenti.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, je voulais écrire _Au cas où, je vous envoie toute la liste, puis vous pourriez me dire si je dois trier **les nouvelles**_ mais comme d'habitude j'ai omis ce que je pouvais omettre.

Comment: *Puis* ne va pas ici. *Au cas où, je vous envoie toute la liste. Pourriez-vous me dire si vous préférez que je trie les nouvelles en fonction du type de publication?*

Comment: :) Quelle belle phrase ! Tant pis, j'ai déjà envoyé mon "puis" mais j'ai remplacé pour "faire un tri". Si mon interlocuteur voyait " en fonction du type de publication" il serait étonné :)

Answer (score 1):

***Au cas où*** est habituellement suivi du conditionnel.

Voir *[Termium plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=97WKhWX3BE-w.html)* :

> Les expressions *au cas où, dans le cas où* et *pour le cas où* signifient « en admettant que, à supposer que ». Elles sont suivies du conditionnel.

Le *bon usage* (Grevisse) dit la même chose :

> Dans les propositions conditionnelles introduites par une subordonnée autre que *si*, [...] le verbe se met au conditionnel quand on exprime l'éventualité, ce qui est assez souvent le cas après *au cas où, au cas que, dans le cas où*....

Et [même l'Académie française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-cas-ou-tu-seras).

Donc la subordonnée est au conditionnel : « Au cas où je vous enverrais...»

Par contre dans la principale le verbe se met au présent.

- Au cas où je vous enverrais toute la liste, dites-moi si je dois la trier.

Cet impératif étant peut-être un peu sec, il est possible de formuler ainsi :

- Au cas où je vous enverrais toute la liste, pourriez-vous me dire (voudriez-vous bien me dire) si je dois la trier.

Mais dans *pourriez-vous me dire* (*voudriez-vous bien me dire*) c'est un conditionnel dit « de politesse » qui n'a aucun lien avec le conditionnel dans la principale.

Comment: Merci, mon "au cas où" signifie "juste in case"  --> _Martin always has spare bulbs in his car, just in case_. J'aurais dû mettre une virgule après "au cas où", je vais corriger.

Comment: Il est possible de mettre "au cas où" à la fin _Je vous envoie toute la liste au cas où_.

Comment: @Oreste J'ai écrit ma réponse sur la base de la première version de la question que j'essayais d'interpréter. La virgule change tout bien sûr. Il faut effectivement mettre une virgule dans le cas où tu l'entends.

Comment: Oui, merci, mais est-ce que "vous me diriez si je dois trier" est correct dans mon contexte ?

Comment: @Oreste Tout à fait. Je vais vous envoyer toute la liste et, au cas où, pourriez-vous me dire si je dois faire la trier ?